# Is getting page "service unavailable" in python selenium scraping suggesting reaching the limit of server?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, multiprocessing

I'm scraping text from a static website (thus very basic driver.find_element). **The issue** is that there are 100 million such pages, i.e. loop over 100 urls, and I want minimize the time.

For now, I'm doing it in a brute-force way: coding it as function, and running 10 pythons at the same time. However, even with 10 pythons, I'm only able to scrape **12000 pages per hour**, which means it will take over 300 days to scrape the whole thing.

I tried to increase to 11-12 number of pythons, however, the "**service unavailable**" page begins to appear. Does it mean that for the server of this website, around 12000 visits per hour is the limit?

I.e., does it mean that even if I change to more efficient "**requests**" package, it won't reduce the time needed to scrape the whole database?

If not, how can I improve the efficiency?

Thank you very much! I just learned Python in 2 days, and let me know if I need to describe the issue more clearly.

Please see below for my code:

```
def func(N):
    from selenium import webdriver
    import csv
    import time
    import pickle
    import pandas as pd
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


    start = time.time()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("\\chromedriver.exe")
    data = {}
    data['zzz'] = []
    data['xxx'] = []
    remove = []

    for i in range(N * 10000 - 9999, N * 10000):
        url = "xxx" + str(i) + ".html"
        print(url)
        driver.get(url)
        count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//head[text()='xxx']")
        temp = check_exists_by_class_name("boxed")
        if temp == 1:
            elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),':')]")
            if 'zzz' in str(elems[0].text):
                zzz = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'zzz')]")
                data['zzz'].append(xxx.text)

                if 'xxx' in str(elems[6].text) or 'xxx' in str(elems[5].text) or 'xxx' in str(elems[4].text):
                    xxx = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),'xxx')]")
                    data['xxx'].append(xxx.text)
                else:
                    data['xxx'].append("None")
        else:
            remove.append(i)

    print("took", time.time() - start, "seconds.")

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
    dataframe.to_csv(filename, index=False, sep='|')
```

Comment: Datamining someone else's site is good way to get yourself blacklisted. Maybe contact the site and ask if they have a public API.

Comment: Actually I contacted them and waited for quite a few days but there are no response and it seems that the website is not closely maintained. There is no email information, only a form submitting problems. What else can I do to get contact with them...I only wish to have this data to merge with my other dataset for research purpose

Comment: using proxy. Then you can increase more

Comment: @kcorlidy Thank you very much! Your suggestion seems to be the right way forward!